# Ionisation energy of Nickel

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Look for the following data for Nickel 
IE1+IE2  2490 kj/mol
IE3+IE4.  8800kj/mol
Total.       11290kj/mol

Hence Nickel can show +2 oxidation state but not +4. 
But according to me Ni in +4 oxidation state can acquire 3d6 and 4s0 which has t2g3 configuration. 
Why do it has high ionisation energy?

Answer (score 1):

Metals with a $d^8$ oxidation state are stabilized by a square-planar molecular orbital configuration. In this configuration, the $\ce{d_{yz},d_{xz},d_{z^2}}$ orbitals are stabilized, while the $\ce{d_{xy}}$ orbital is slightly destabilized and the $\ce{d_{x^2-y^2}}$ is severely destabilized (however, in $d^8$ species this orbital is unoccupied). The amount of stability provided by the square planar configuration is far greater than the amount of stability provided by the low-spin $d^6$ configuration.

[This is a good online powerpoint that shows the stabilization.](http://www.mpilkington.com/Lecture_9.pdf)